# Помогите подключить mongoose-auto-increment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Есть:

app.js

```
...
 mongoose =     require('mongoose');
 mongoose.connect(config.url);
...
```

config.js

```
module.exports = {
   'secret': 'ilovescotchyscotch',
   'url': 'mongodb://localhost/bd'
};
```

модель user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Admin',{
   username: String,
   password: String,
   email: String,
   role: { type: String, default: "user" },
   soft_token: { type: String, default: 0 }
});
```

подключаю модель в роутер index.js

```
var User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    new User({
       //..//..//
    });
});
```

Помогите прикрутить сюда модуль mongoose-auto-increment.

Comment: Расскажите поподробнее, что вы уже попробовали, и что у вас не получилось. Вы пытались следовать примерам с официальной страницы модуля? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment

Comment: В примере все в одном файле, а у меня все раскидано. Не могу разложить по полкам.

Answer (score 0):

1. В app.js пред (!!!) подключением к БД:

```html
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
```

2. После подключения к БД:

```html
autoIncrement.initialize(connection);
```

3. В модели после Schema но перед экспортом:

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const user = new Schema({
    "_id": {
        "type": "Schema.Types.ObjectId",
        "required": true
    },
    "myField": {
        "type": "Number",
        "required": true,
        "unique": true
    },
...

...
});

userSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, { model: 'User', field: 'myField' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', user);
```

Вариант модели где нужно автоинкремент для _id (тип number !!!):

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const area = new Schema({
        _id: {
            type: Number,
        },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'is required!'],
        unique: [true, 'A record with this name already exists in the database'],
    },
    },
    {
    timestamps: {}
    }
).plugin(AutoIncrement);

module.exports = mongoose.model('areas', area);
```

Comment: Вместо сниппетов пользуйтесь выделением как код [Ctrll+K].